# prove $x = (b-a) \mod m$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $(ai+x)\mod m = b $ then how can we prove that $x = (b-a)\mod m$?

If it is not correct then what is correct value for $x$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Please use the command `\pmod` to get a better form for the module operator such as 
$$
ai+x\pmod{m}=b
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just use Definitions.

$A\equiv B\pmod m$ means $m|A-B$ means there exists  an integer $k$ so that $mk = A- B$ means there exists an integer so that  $A = B + mk$.

So if $ai+x \equiv b \pmod m$ then there exists a $k$ so that $ai+x = b + mk$, but then there exists an integer $k$ so that $x=b - ai + mk$.  So $x\equiv b-ai\pmod m$.